# In Docker Jmeter HTML Report is not generating

Tags: linux, docker, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

The issue is Container stopped after docker completing the Jmeter hit.

Docker File last Line :

> - CMD jmeter -n -t Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l .csv -e -o Get_Ping_Node_API2.html

Running:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sumit/docker-jmeter$ docker exec -it 3f2092a9895d bash
>   Error response from daemon: Container 3f2092a9895d881b97459af9f9c7982e06c696d1b0d4dc1484ee9dd75a3368ee is not running
>   ubuntu@ubuntu:~/sumit/docker-jmeter$

Answer (score 0):

You're misinterpreting command line options:

As per this documentation:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Parameter following **-o** should be a folder, you have put a file, it should be:

> -o OUTPUT_FOLDER

Parameter following **-l** should be a csv file, you have put **.csv** which is only a suffix

It should be:

> -l results.csv

Answer (score 0):

Your JMeter execution line is not very correct, you should amend it like:

> CMD jmeter -n -t Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l **result**.csv -e -o **Get_Ping_Node_API2**

1. `-l` command line argument assumes **file** where results will be stored, you cannot leave the filename empty
2. `-o` command-line argument assumes **folder** where the dashboard will be generated, you should remove .html extension from it

References:

- [Non-GUI Mode (Command Line mode)](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Example Dockerfile you can use as a basis, it executes `Test.jmx` file from JMeter's "extras" folder, feel free to amend it as required to kick off your own test plan:

```
# 1
FROM alpine:3.6

# 2
LABEL maintainer=”vincenzo.marrazzo@domain.personal>

# 3
ARG JMETER_VERSION="4.0"

# 4
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV MIRROR_HOST http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/apache/jmeter
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL ${MIRROR_HOST}/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/

# 5
RUN    apk update \
        && apk upgrade \
        && apk add ca-certificates \
        && update-ca-certificates \
            && apk add --update openjdk8-jre tzdata curl unzip bash \
            && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome /etc/localtime \
            && echo "Europe/Rome" >  /etc/timezone \
        && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
        && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
        && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz  \
        && mkdir -p /opt  \
        && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt  \
        && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

# 6
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-dummy/0.2/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-dummy-0.2.jar
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter/0.5/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.5.jar

# 7
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN

#8
WORKDIR ${JMETER_BIN}

#9
CMD ./jmeter -n -t ../extras/Test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o Get_Ping_Node_API2
```

Comment: Not Getting OUTPUT

CMD jmeter -n -t Get_Ping_Node_API.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o Get_Ping_Node_API1

Comment: How can i print the html file in docker.. Please help me

Comment: `docker cp your_container_id:/opt/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin/Get_Ping_Node_API2 /path/to/your/local/drive`